# How do i make a guild based leaderboard command in discord.js

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

Guys so I am using quickmongo for my economy bot and I want to make a guild leaderboard command which will show names of users who are in the guild only, and I store the datas globally. I used this code before but it crashes my bot if the command is run in big servers.

```js
let xx = [];
await Promise.all(
    message.guild.members.cache.map(async(member) => {
        let id = member.id;
        let nick = await db.fetch(`nick_${id}`) || member.user.tag;
        let bal = await db.fetch(`mon_${id}`);
        if ((!bal || bal === 0)) return;
            xx.push({ data: bal, ID: `${nick}` });
            console.log(xx);
        })
    );

    let xy = xx.sort((a, b) => b.data - a.data);
    if (xy.lenght < 1) return message.reply('No rich people here -_-');
    xy.length = 5;

    var final = "";
    for (var i in xy) {
        let path = '️';
        let ind = xy.indexOf(xy[i]) + 1;
        if (ind == 1) path = '';
        else if (ind == 2) path = '';
        else if (ind == 3) path = '';
        final += `${path} **${xy[i].data.toLocaleString()}** - ${xy[i].ID}\n`
    }
);
```

So I am trying to get a way to get guild leaderboard without caching through the whole guild.

Comment: You'd need to go through every guild members data you have in your database, add their level, name and anything else you want to include in your leaderboard into an array and then sort the array from highest level to lowest level. You haven't provided information such as the database you used so unfortunately this is a very brief explanation.